# Загрузка локализации извне. ResourseBundle.getBundle() не находит .properties в папке /bin

Tags: java, локализация, properties

```
final private static Locale current_locale = Locale.getDefault();   
final private static ResourceBundle dictionary = getDictionary();

private static ResourceBundle getDictionary()
{   try 
    {   return ResourceBundle.getBundle(getApplicationPath.Do() + "/Language/dictionary", current_locale);  }               
    catch (NullPointerException | MissingResourceException e)
    {   Quit.Error("Local language " + current_locale.getDisplayLanguage() + " wasn't found in database.");
        return null;    }   
}
```

Локализация хранится в папке, где запускается программа. У меня она лежит, соответственно, в `/Workspace/project/bin/` и далее `Language/dictionary_en.properties`.
Как видите, адрес в .getBundle() указан полный, папка `/bin/Language/` в classpath добавлена - в Project Explorer Эклипса я вижу её наравне с другими библиотеками, и внутри лежат файлы моей локализации.

Но я никак не могу засечь причину, по которой компилятор не находит мой файл.

Comment: Не могли бы проверить чему равно `getApplicationPath.Do() + "/Language/dictionary"` Например `String bundlePath = getApplicationPath.Do() + "/Language/dictionary"; System.out.println(bundlePath);`

Comment: Указывает ровно на то место, где лежит dictionary. Все остальные файлы, не относящиеся к .properties, программа исправно подхватывает из /bin. Path: /D:/_PROJECTS_/Java/Workspace/Project/bin/Language/dictionary

Comment: Не знаю может так и надо, но какой-то странный путь. Его начало.

Comment: Забыл добавить, что кодировка .properties - файла UTF-8 (если это имеет значение)

Answer (score 1):

Я, похоже, так и не разорбался, как добавлять файлы .properties в classpath. И не понял зачем.
Но нашёл способ подгрузить файл из файловой системы (filesystem).
Загрузка словаря:

```
UTF8ResourceLoader $utf8loader = new UTF8ResourceLoader();
$utf8loader.path =  "D:\\_PROJECTS_\\Java\\Workspace\\Project\\bin\\Language\\";
ClassLoader $cloader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ResourceBundle dictionary = null;
try{    return dictionary = $utf8loader.newBundle("dictionary", current_locale, "java.properties", $cloader, false);    }
catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | IOException e)
{   Quit.Error("Error occured while loading dictionary resource bundle." ); 
    return null;    }
```

Чтобы подгружать файлы локализации, нужно переписать метод класса ResourceBundle:

```
public class UTF8ResourceLoader extends Control 
{
    public String path;

    public void setPath(String path)
    {   this.path = path;   }

    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
    throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        if (!format.equals("java.properties")) 
            return null;
        String bundleName = baseName + "_" + locale.getLanguage() + format.substring(format.lastIndexOf('.'));  
        ResourceBundle bundle = null;
        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try 
        {   File file = new File(path, bundleName);
            if (file.isFile())                                                      
            {   fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(reader);    }
        } finally 
        {   IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);      }
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

IOutils - это из Apache Common IO
Не все языки кодируются с помощью ANSII, поэтому некодируемые символы нужно заменять специальным кодом `title=\u0414\u0438\u0430\u043f\u0430\u0437\u043e\u043d\u044b`
(с)http://www.skipy.ru/technics/localization.html

Шапка

```
final private static Locale current_locale = Locale.getDefault();   
final private static ResourceBundle dictionary = getDictionary();
```

позволяет задать значения и сделать константными current_locale & dictionary, и далее все значения также сделать final-контстантами:

```
final public static String art = dictionary.getString("art");
final public static String type = dictionary.getString("type");
...
```